# Intel® HD Graphics 4600 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I've been having problems ever since I installed Ubuntu with having my second monitor.

I use a Gigabyte GTX 970 for my main monitor, and Intel® HD Graphics 4600 is my integrated graphics card for my second monitor.

The second monitor works at first (when I boot my computer it shows the loading screen), but just freezes at that frame from then and doesn't get recognised by Ubuntu at all.

[image: "Additional Drivers"]

Also, I've tried using the Intel Graphics Updater, and it installed a few things, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: I just realised, I should probably specify that I'm just connecting the monitor to the graphics card to connect it to my GTX 970 (This works in Windows 7)

Comment: It may work in Windows, it doesn't in Linux. Use one or the other. Your Nvidia card certainly has more than one output...

Comment: Yes, but it only has DVI output other than one HDMI port, I'm trying to connect VGA, plus this has worked before on Ubuntu, as well as in the installer when I just recently installed it

Comment: *this has worked before on Ubuntu*... I very much doubt it. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Eh, whatever, might as well just get a DVI to VGA converter, it'll probably be useful in the future anyways